# How can i print accents and ñ in C, setlocale doesnt work for me

Tags: locale

my native language is spanish and id like to print accents like á é í ó ú or ñ, and i tried to use the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    printf("áéíóúñ");

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is: A¡AcA-A3AºA±

my computer has windows 10 and is in english btw but the setlocale trick should be working. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    printf("áéíóúñ");

    return 0;
}
```

and expected to print á é í ó ú ñ and got A¡AcA-A3AºA±